# Headers changed when converting spss file to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, spss

I converted spss file to pandas using SavReaderWriter. However after that, my variables' names are in the first row like b'variable_name'. How to just select the variable name?

```
data=spss.SavReader('file name', returnHeader=True)
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
df.loc[0]=df.loc[0].apply(lambda x: x[2:len(x)-1])
```

However the result is b'riable_nam' (the b'' format still persisted). 
What should I do to purify the variable name?

Comment: Can you please provide a snippet of your dataframe? Just to visualise.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works (without seeing the data, i am guessing here)

```
df.loc[0]=df.loc[0].apply(lambda x: x.str.split("‘")[1], axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks so much for your help. I replaced your code and I got this SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: My dataframe was like

Comment: One of the quote symbols was incorrect. Can you please try again? Adjust the code so that the single quote in your string is in between the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

SavReaderWriter returns bytes when reading SPSS metadata. 
Example of a label: `b'Data id'`. 
Type of var in python returns: `<class 'bytes'>`. 
Therefore solution is to decode it, sample code is below:

```
with rw.SavHeaderReader("tesFile.sav", ioUtf8=False) as header:
metadata = header.all()
varLabels = metadata.varLabels
for var, lab in varLabels.items():
    decodedLabel = lab.decode("utf-8")
```